# WordPress Cron Events for running scheduled jobs on CiviCRM

Tags: cron, scheduled-job

Need your help...I'm new to CiviCRM and I'm trying to create a cron job for automatically running all the CiviCRM scheduled jobs..I was wondering if it's possible to do this through the WordPress Cron Events Tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CiviCRM  go to Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs